# Data from ArrayList into Listview

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Simply put, I'm retrieving data from an external RSS XML in the class 'HandleXML' (called form MainActivity), parsing/storing it in an ArrayList then outputting it to a Listview. I understand an adapter is needed to get the ArrayList values to the Listview, but for one reason or another mine isn't going any farther than parsing the data into the ArrayList.
I think I have all the components, maybe just the placement is incorrect?

[EDIT]
To clarify, when either button in the activity is pressed logcat reports a null exception with the HandleXML.printItems. The ArrayList appears to be filled but nothing is appearing in the Listview.

*If it looks like homework, this was someone else's which I am using to learn myself. I am a hobbyist not a student.

Any help is appreciated.

MainActivity.java

```
//define buttons
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);

        //on-click listeners for buttons; retrieve XML info
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                obj = new HandleXML(roadsURL);
                obj.fetchXML();
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                obj = new HandleXML(proadsURL);
                obj.fetchXML();
            }
        });
```

HandleXML.java

```
public class HandleXML extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = HandleXML.class.getSimpleName(); //Logcat tag for debugging
    private String urlString = null;
    private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;

    public HandleXML(String url){
        this.urlString = url;
    }

    public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList(); //arraylist for item objects
        String text = null;
        Item currentItem = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType(); //return event type from XML

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = null;

                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: //parse by item tag, then by sub-tags
                        name = myParser.getName();
                        if (name.equals("item")){
                            currentItem = new Item(); //new item object for arraylist
                        } else if (currentItem != null){
                            if (name.equals("title")){
                                currentItem.title = text;
                            } else if (name.equals("description")){
                                currentItem.description = text;
                            } 
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText(); //retrieve text value from tag
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        name = myParser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && currentItem != null) {
                            items.add(currentItem); //add to arraylist
                            //Log.e(TAG, "parse: added new item "); //DEBUG - print the code to logcat
                        }
                }

                event = myParser.next();
            }
            printItems(items); //get arraylist info to screen
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void printItems(ArrayList<Item> items)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.info); //scroll area listview

        //adapter with pre-defined layout for listview, source arraylist
        ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 , items);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); //link adapter to listview
    }

    public void fetchXML(){
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    //HttpURLConnection settings
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null); //set XML source as stream

                    parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
                    stream.close();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to describe exactly what the problem is. What shows on the screen? Is there a crash? Is there an error? Be specific about exactly what you're trying to accomplish and in what way that is not happening for you. Explaining your issue as "for one reason or another mine isn't going any farther than parsing the data" is pretty vague.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a line to clarify the exact nature of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should consider using an ASYNC task for this as you can control the data flow more precisely than a standard thread. You can pass in a reference to the listview and update it in the `onPostExecute()`

Consider this:

```
        //on-click listeners for buttons; retrieve XML info
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DownloadFilesTask(listview_item_or_adapter_reference).execute(roadsURL);
            }
        });


 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

     private static final String TAG = HandleXML.class.getSimpleName();                 
     //Logcat tag for debugging
     private String urlString = null;
     private XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactoryObject;
     private ListView item;

     public DownloadFilesTask(ListView item){
     this.item = item;
     }

     protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
 try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) 
                    url.openConnection();
                    //HttpURLConnection settings
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
                    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    conn.setDoInput(true);

                    // Starts the query
                    conn.connect();
                    InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

                    xmlFactoryObject = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                    XmlPullParser myparser = xmlFactoryObject.newPullParser();

                    myparser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                    myparser.setInput(stream, null); //set XML source as stream


                    stream.close();
                }

                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded  data,pasring now...");
         parseXMLAndStoreIt(myparser);
         //update item or adapter here
     }






       private void printItems(ArrayList<Item> items)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.info); //scroll area listview

        //adapter with pre-defined layout for listview, source arraylist
        ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 , items);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter); //link adapter to listview
    }

      public void parseXMLAndStoreIt(XmlPullParser myParser) {
        int event;
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList(); //arraylist for item objects
        String text = null;
        Item currentItem = null;

        try {
            event = myParser.getEventType(); //return event type from XML

            while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String name = null;

                switch (event){
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG: //parse by item tag, then by sub-tags
                        name = myParser.getName();
                        if (name.equals("item")){
                            currentItem = new Item(); //new item object for arraylist
                        } else if (currentItem != null){
                            if (name.equals("title")){
                                currentItem.title = text;
                            } else if (name.equals("description")){
                                currentItem.description = text;
                            } 
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = myParser.getText(); //retrieve text value from tag
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        name = myParser.getName();
                        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && currentItem != null) {
                            items.add(currentItem); //add to arraylist
                            //Log.e(TAG, "parse: added new item "); //DEBUG - print the code to logcat
                        }
                }

                event = myParser.next();
            }
            printItems(items); //get arraylist info to screen
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the click listeners in your code you are creating objects of a class which extends Activity.java `obj = new HandleXML(proadsURL);` This should not be done. Its not us, the end users (using Android framework to design our applications) who create the Activity. Its the framework who creates the Activity and manages its life cycle. We register our Activity in AndroidMenifest.xml and then we can start the activity.

I suggest you to understand the life cycle of an `Activity`. Android framework has been beautifully designed and it provides call back methods for activity life cycles.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

We should `set` the `contentView` for the Activity. In the `contentView` you need to hook your `ListView`.

Also we need to define our Launcher activity in the `AndroidMenifest.xml`. If you wish to start another activity when some event occurs then you should study about as how `startActivity` method is used.

http://themasterworld.com/starting-new-activity-on-button-click-android/

Also respecting the SRP principle (Single responsibility Principle), I would suggest you to not have parsing of XML in your activity. Do not use it for that sole purpose. Activity is  to provide a user interface.